# Distinction between web page and RESTful web service at runtime?

Tags: web, rest

I have a URL which could be a web page or a RESTful web service. Is it possible to make distinction between the two at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

A web page is a RESTful Web Service.

Most likely not unless the RESTful Service has some special http header to identify itself or uses some special mimetype that's not html.

Answer (score 0):

Check the content-type header of the response. A web service should return an HTTP-compliant document that is not of the "text/html" variety. Usually you can expect XML or JSON, but a service could return an image, plain text or other data that doesn't comply to those formats.

Read [RESTful Web Services](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/) for a more complete description.